# SignalR duplicating responses

Tags: nginx, load, duplicates, signalr

I'm using SignalR with Redis as a message bus on a server that sits behind an Nginx proxy for load balancing. I used SignalR's PersistentConnection class to write a simple chat program that broadcasts messages to users belonging to the same certain group. Users are added to a group in OnConnectedAsync, removed in OnDisconnectAsync, and the user-to-group mapping is deterministic.

Currently, the client side falls back to long polling for whatever reason (I'm not entirely sure why), and whenever the client sets up a new connection after waiting for and receiving a response, seemingly at random, the server will sometimes respond to the new connection immediately with the previous response, despite there having only been one POST.

The message ID's tend to differ by exactly one, (the smaller ID coming first), with the rest of the response remaining the same. I logged some debug info and am quite positive that my override of OnReceivedAsync is sending one response per one request. I tried the same implementation without the Redis message bus, and got the same problem. Running locally (with long polling) however yielded good results so I suspect that the problem might be with the way the message bus might be buffering messages to refresh clients who might not be caught up, and some weird timing with the cutting/setting up of connections with the Nginx load balancer, but beyond that, I am very much at a loss.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Further investigation reveals that duplication occurs at somewhat regular intervals of approximately 20-30 seconds. I'm led to believe that the message expiration in the message bus might have something to do with the bug.

EDIT: Bug can be seen here: http://tinyurl.com/9q5t3va

The server is simply broadcasting a counter being sent by the client. You will notice some responses are duplicated every 20 or so.

Comment: File an issue on github with a repro and repro steps.

Comment: Having trouble reproducing the bug locally. Will file a report when (if) I am able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the number of worker processes in the IIS (6.0) Server Manager from 2 to 1 solved the problem.